# Compactness: Opens vs. Neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples

*Disclaimer: This thread is a record of thoughts.*

**Discussion**
Given a compact set.

> Do mere neighborhood covers admit finite subcovers?
>   $$C\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}N_i\implies C\subseteq N_1\cup\ldots N_n$$
>   *(The idea is that neighborhoods are in some sense fat.)*

**Application**

Given a locally compact space.

Every compact set has a compact neighborhood base:
$$C\subseteq U:\quad N\subseteq U\quad(C\subseteq N^°)$$
*(The above would give clues how to prove this.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counterexample**

Consider the compact set: $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$

Cover it by neighborhoods:
$$(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cup\{x+2\}\quad(0\leq x\leq1)$$

Then it admits no finite subcover!

**Discrepancy**

Consider the compact set: $\{1\}\cup\{-1\}$

Cover it by neighborhoods for all points:
$$(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)\cup(-1-\varepsilon,-1+\varepsilon)\quad(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)\cup\{-1\}$$

Then it admits a bad finite subcover!

*Essence: The power of opens lied in them being neighborhoods of its point.*

Comment: The problem is that a neighborhood is not neighborhood of all points it covers. Hovever if for each point of the space there is its neihborhood in the cover, it has finite subcover.

Comment: Aaaah - very enlightening - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call a space $X$ *really, truly compact* if every cover of $X$ by sets with nonempty interior has a finite subcover.

It is not hard too show that $X$ is *really, truly compact* if and only if $X \setminus U$ is finite for every nonempty open $U \subseteq X$ (*i.e.*, the topology on $X$ is coarser than the co-finite topology on $X$):

> If $X$ has a nonempty open $U \subseteq X$ such that $X \setminus U$ is infinite, then $\{ U \cup \{ x \} : x \in X \setminus U \}$ is a cover of $X$ by sets with nonempty interior with no finite subcover.
>
> If $X \setminus U$ is finite for every nonempty open $U \subseteq X$, consider any cover $\mathcal A$ of $X$ by subsets of $X$ with nonempty interior. Pick any $A_0 \in \mathcal A$. Then $X \setminus A_0 \subseteq X \setminus \operatorname{Int} (A_0)$ is finite, say $\{ x_1 , \ldots , x_n \}$, so we may pick $A_1 , 
> \ldots , A_n$ from $\mathcal A$ so that $x_i \in A_i$. Then $\{ A_0 , A_1 , \ldots , A_n \}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal A$.

From this it follows that a T<sub>1</sub>-space is *really, truly compact* if and only if it has the co-finite topology, and therefore the *really, truly compact* subsets of $\mathbb R$ are exactly the finite subsets.